# GeoServer PointSymbolizer graphic artifact when zoomed

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, circle

I'm using GeoServer 2.14.0, I created a red circle using PointSymbolizer with size=35. But in some cases, the map shows this artifact when I zoom in:

[image]

Basically the map still shows parts of the circle rendered with the previous zoom. I guess the problem is the tile render/refresh, a problem similar to [Leaflet.js rendering 'chopped' WMS point symbols for variable sized points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142031/leaflet-js-rendering-chopped-wms-point-symbols-for-variable-sized-points) or http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Geoserver-cut-off-symbols-close-to-tile-edges-td3798283.html

Any changes to the GeoWebCache settings (metatiles size and gutter) didn’t solve the problem. After a few tries, I realized that the larger the point size, the more evident the artifact is.

Do you have any suggestions?

‌

Comment: did you clear your caches (both server and client) after you last changed the symbol size in the SLD?

Comment: Yes, I did. Even after change metatiles size.

Comment: GeoServer 2.14.0 is old an unsupported by now, is the same happening with a 2.16.x release?